# Redirect in route to unknown action

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

I need to go to action in controller which will be note in second parameter
While I see var variable I can not go to the action

```
Route::get('/seeds/{var}', function($var){
dump($var);
    return redirect()->action('MakeSeedingController@index');
});
```

I receive an error
http://prntscr.com/i0ebrf
While and controller and action are presents

Comment: Do you have `MakeSeedingController@index` defined in your route?

Comment: No Actialy I want that var see without index action.Please Write How it have to be

Comment: You need to have a function named index in your MakeSeedingController file, otherwise, you have to redirect to a route or URL.

Comment: I have index action in this file But receive error

Comment: php artisan config:clear and I am sure you have a typo on controller name

Comment: Nothing changed I have no typo on controller name

Comment: http://prntscr.com/i0ge6h

Comment: http://prntscr.com/i0gejv

Comment: Route::get('/seeds/index', 'MakeSeedingController@index')->name('seeds');This variant is working but that -> Route::get('/seeds/{var}', function ($var) {
    return redirect()->action('MakeSeedingController@' . $var); Not Working HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what you missed.
Because you are trying to redirect to `MakeSeedingController@index` action, then you must define another `route`.
Try this:

```
Route::get('/seeds/{var}', function($var){
dump($var);
    return redirect()->action('MakeSeedingController@index');
});
Route::get('/someroute/{var}', 'MakeSeedingController@index');
```

Comment: Actialy I need such construction not only to to index action Route::get('/seeds/{var}', function ($var) { return redirect()->action('MakeSeedingController@' . $var); But even to index not working I dont understand why

Comment: Then you must define the routes of these actions before you try to redirect. Because this is actually the redirections to another route.

Answer (score 0):

This constraction works but I dont understand why and what does it mean App::call If somebode knows please explain

```
Route::get('/seeds/{var}', function ($var) {
    return App::call('App\Http\Controllers\MakeSeedingController@' . $var);
});
```